# Customize individual bootstrap CSS for element in R Shiny UI

Tags: html, css, r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

I am trying to style a specific actionButton in my R Shiny UI using bootstrap. I don't want to style all the action buttons in the same way; just this one. The action button in the UI I am trying to style looks like:

```
actionButton("btnFinalizeProjectInformation", label = "I have checked my entries and am ready to move to the next step.")
```

In my bootstrap file, I tried to style this button with this entry, which I placed at the bottom of my bootstrap file:

```
#btnFinalizeProjectInformation{
   color: #fff;
   background: #3655d3 -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b33477), to(#D33682)) repeat-x;
   background: #3655d3 linear-gradient(180deg, #b33477, #D33682) repeat-x;
   border-color: #3655d3;
}
```

I also tried making my own class. When I did this, the actionbutton looked like this:

```
actionButton("btnFinalizeProjectInformation", label = "I have checked my entries and am ready to move to the next step.", class = "btnFinalizeProjectInformation")
```

And the entry in the bootstrap looked like:

```
.btnFinalizeProjectInformation{
   color: #fff;
   background: #3655d3 -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b33477), to(#D33682)) repeat-x;
   background: #3655d3 linear-gradient(180deg, #b33477, #D33682) repeat-x;
   border-color: #3655d3;
}
```

Neither of these methods worked. I am not sure whether this is because the bootstrap entry is getting written over by another button related entry in the bootstrap, or if I am doing something else wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where do you put the CSS ? In a `tags$style` ?

Comment: Use your browser inspector tool to figure out what's going on. For example, view the webpage in the Chrome browser. Right-click on the button and select "Inspect" from the context menu. The DevTools window will open and in the right-hand pane you will see the Styles tab listing all the styles applied to the button. You can see a) if your custom style is being applied, or b) if another style is overriding it. Then you can take action.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I put the CSS in a bootstrap file that I attach to the UI using the "theme" arguement in fluidpage. I will try tags$style tomorrow at work and see if that helps.

Comment: [Here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) is a related article.

Comment: Update: tags$style worked. However, I ended up using a very convenient package called shinyJS, since I was trying to show/hide elements.